# find the k th smallest element in the union of 2 sorted lists of size m and n with efficiency log(k)

Tags: algorithm

Find the k th smallest element in the union of 2 sorted lists of size m and n

with efficiency log(k) ,,  i have done a lot of thinking and searching i also got the

pesedocode and the explain to it ... so far i still doesn't get or understand the

the question right .. any help will be appreciated....

Comment: Please outline what you have so far. I don't think anyone wants to do your homework for you. :-)

Comment: If there's something there you specifically don't understand, ask about it.  If not, show your current work, however stuck you are, and we should be able to help you get going again.

Comment: @drewk: He said he doesn't understand the question. He didn't ask for the answer.

Comment: @Giuseppe: Please don't add homework tag without clarifying with the questioner first. And moreover, adding homework tags in now frowned upon.

Comment: @Moron:  Could you point me to something recent about homework tags?  Last I saw, Jeff thought them worthwhile, unlike all other meta tags.  Also, this is almost certainly homework.

Comment: @David: Maybe I am mistaken, but some user referred me to some thread just a week or so back. Possibly this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. It could be old.

Comment: @Moron:  Some of it is old, some comments new.  I was asking because I might well be wrong here, but the last I saw homework tags were encouraged for homework.  I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception which is fairly recent, after the expulsion of meta tags, and seems to have failed to reach an agreement.

Comment: @David: I was under that impression too, but the meta thread I linked is apparently _the_ thread on homework. In any case, the tag to this question was added without any clarification from OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have to sets, say `{ 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 98, 1993 }` and `{ 2, 5, 8, 10, 88 }`.
And you want to find the third smallest element.

That means m=8, n=5, and k=3.
Visually inspecting these sets, you'll see that the answer is 4.
Your finding algorithm has to find the correct value within `O(log(k))` (that's "big O").

That means if your algorithm finds the element with a number of steps `N = n1 + n2 + ...`, where each of `n1, n2, ...` is a function of k, the rate of growth of all of `n1, n2...` must be less than or equal to the rate of growth of log(k).

If that doesn't make sense, aim to find the element in less than k steps (where k > 1).

Comment: your explain is quiet excellent but i want to focus on the part of how did we get 4 if we consider k=3 ?? i am confused a little       about this ...  so i appreciate any clarifying

Comment: You're looking for the kth smallest element among the union of the two sets. So `k = 1, 2, 3, ...` is a search for the `smallest, 2nd smallest, 3rd smallest, ...` element among the two sets. Therefore, `k=1 -> 1`, `k=2 -> 2`, `k=3 -> 4`, etc.